# Automation Testing for Chat Based Application or Push Notification

Tags: testing, mobile, automation, google-cloud-messaging

I Wonder if is there any possibility of testing the Mobile Chat based application through automation scripts. Lets say we have whatsapp, FB, Skype chat based apps. How people will be doing testing for these apps apart from manual?

I can automate on one side of mobile through some automation tools selendroid, see test and some other like open application, search a contact ,and send text message. But how on the other side of mobile will be automated ? like as soon as it receives message it replies with same message.

Even how push notification automation testing is done?
I can see some apps which do auto reply for sms , but thats not works for testing.

Kindly suggest your thoughts on this.

Comment: You can create a Beta version of app which includes an auto response function when message is received. Then install the Beta version on all your testing devices to see if your server is sending and responding information correctly. After testing is done, remove the auto response functionality. It's just an idea, hope this provided you some hint.

Comment: Appreciate your idea. But, in general is this the process people may undergo for chat based apps and push notifications ? sorry just working on some white paper so thought to dig in deep but i couldnt able to get clues over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have automated the chat apps for mobile on iOS and Android. Automating both sides is possible. 
For ex- you have a scenario that you want to login to your chat app account and send a message to another user. 
You have to use two devices. Connect them to your system give them different names. Like you mentioned seetest.Two devices can be connected to it at a time.
Lets say device1 and device2.
 Pseudo script -

1. Device1 activate
2. Launch chat app in device1 - login
3. Device2 activate
4. Launch chat app in device2 - login
5. Device1 activate -select a user(which logged in from device2)- send message
6. Device2 - check the notification object or the object which will display this message and compare the property say "text" with the message sent from device2.

You can guide the script using the functions from the mobile automation tool to run your script step on a device with particular name or identifier.

Comment: Please learn how to format with Markdown (see all of the formatting tips to the right when you wrote your question) and reformat it so it's readable.